# Multimap containing pairs?

Tags: c++, stl, multimap, stdmap, std-pair

Is it possible for a multimap to contain within it pairs? IE, rather then being defined as `multimap<char,int>` for instance, it would be defined as `multimap<pair, pair`>?

How would this multimap then be sorted? Also, how would one access the individual contents of each pair?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Is it possible for a multimap to contain within it pairs?*

Yes its possible.

*How would this multimap then be sorted?*

By the key/first pair (ie, first by the first element of the first pair, then by the second element of the first pair).

*Also, how would one access the individual contents of each pair?*

```
multimap<pair <T1, T2>, pair<T3, T4> >::iterator it = mymultimap.begin();
it->first.first;
it->first.second;
it->second.first;
it->second.second;
```

In other words, a multimap of pairs works exactly as expected!

*Update:*
Also, I'd like to add that I discourage any use of pairs of pairs, it makes the code very hard to read, use structs with real variable names instead.

Comment: Small point, you need to define operator `<` for comparison or provide object that compares these pairs in definition of multimap

Comment: You shouldn't define operator< for `std::pair`; it's not your type. In fact, it already is defined.

Comment: @Artyom: operator< for std::pair is defined as I said, it compares first::operator<, and if they are equal, it compares by second::operator<

Comment: +1 for concise and straightforward answer. And yes, pair already implements operator<.