# Insertion into pair that is mapped value in multimap in C++

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

Found this [Multimap containing pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099947/multimap-containing-pairs), but it is not much help

How would I insert two strings into `pair`? Below, my two failed attempts.

```
multimap<string, pair<string,string> > mymm;
mymm["Alex"] = std::pair<"000","000">; //errors
mymm.insert(pair<string, pair<string, string> > 
           ("Alex", std::pair<"000","000">); // errors out as well
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010, 32 bit. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mymm.insert(make_pair("Alex",make_pair("000","000")));
```

A multimap doesn't allow lookup using operator [], since there may be more than one match.

make_pair is a convenient way to create a pair without having to specify the types explicitly.  Without using make_pair, you would need to do something like this:

```
mymm.insert(pair<string,pair<string,string> >("Alex",pair<string,string>("000","000")));
```

Comment: Thanks! `map` uses `[]` operator to insert the values. I was thinking `multimap` behaves the same way.

Comment: It might be worth explaining the actual error he gets from calling std::pair<"000","000">; he's mixing up template arguments with constructor arguments, which shows a more fundamental problem than not knowing the API for multimap…

Comment: @abarnert: Maybe the example I added will help.

Comment: I personally preffer using `MapType::value_type` instead of `make_pair` because you can _see_ to what map type the data belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

`std::pair<string,string>("000","000")` should do it.

The code contained between < and > indicates the types of the variables you're inserting-- in this case strings

Comment: `mymm["Alex"]` is nonsensical.